# Why does Weka RandomForest gives me a different result than Scikit RandomForestClassifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, weka, random-forest

I am getting peculiar differences in results between WEKA and scikit while using the same RandomForest technique and the same dataset. With scikit I am getting an AUC around 0.62 (all the time, for I did extensive testing). However, with WEKA, im getting results close to 0.79. Thats a huge difference!

The dataset I tested the algorithms on is KC1.arff, of which I put a copy in my public dropbox folder https://dl.dropbox.com/u/30688032/KC1.arff. For WEKA, I simply downloaded the .jar file from http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/downloading.html. In WEKA, I set the cross-validation parameter as 10-fold, the dataset as KC1.arff, the algorithm as  "RandomForest -l 19 -K 0 -S 1". Then ran the code! Once you generate the results in WEKA, it should be saved as a file, .csv or .arff. Read that file and check the column 'Area_under_ROC', it should be somewhat close to 0.79.

Below is the code for the scikit's RandomForest

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import *
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

def read_arff(f):
    from scipy.io import arff
    data, meta = arff.loadarff(f) 
    return DataFrame(data)

def kfold(clr,X,y,folds=10):
    from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold
    from sklearn import metrics
    auc_sum=0
    kf = StratifiedKFold(y, folds)
    for train_index, test_index in kf:
        X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
        clr.fit(X_train, y_train)
        pred_test = clr.predict(X_test)
        print metrics.auc_score(y_test,pred_test)
        auc_sum+=metrics.auc_score(y_test,pred_test)

    print 'AUC: ',  auc_sum/folds
    print  "----------------------------" 



#read the dataset
X=read_arff('KC1.arff')
y=X['Defective']

#changes N, and Y to 0, and 1 respectively
s = np.unique(y)
mapping = Series([x[0] for x in enumerate(s)], index = s)  
y=y.map(mapping) 
del X['Defective']

#initialize random forests (by defualt it is set to 10 trees)
rf=RandomForestClassifier()

#run algorithm
kfold(rf,np.array(X),y)

#You will get an average AUC around 0.62 as opposed to 0.79 in WEKA
```

Please keep in mind that the real auc value, as shown in relevant papers' experimental results, is around 0.79, so the problem lies on my implementation that uses the scikit random forests.

Your kind help will be highly appreciated!!

Thank you very much!

Comment: First, you should make sure that you're using the same parameters for the RF implementation in scikit. Second, as the name suggests, there's some randomness associated with the results -- you mention that you did extensive testing, but it might not have been extensive enough. Third, the partition of your data will also affect the results. In particular, you should make sure that the folds you generate are stratified.

Comment: I did do VERY extensive testing! with scikit, the values never exceeded 0.64, and the auc values i get are always close to 0.57. With WEKA, I also did lots of testing, and I always get values close to 0.79, so I dont think the randomness is the factor here. For both algorithms I used 10-fold, which also gave me the same results as using 70% training and 30% testing split, so, i think my method for validation is not a factor as well. However, you might be right on the parameters, I tried my best to set them to be the same, thats why I am asking if you can kindly find the flaw :) :)! Thank you!

Comment: My wild guess is that your folds in scikit are not stratified.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, can you kindly show me where the folds are not stratified? I am using the same approach explained in scikit. Thanks

Comment: According to http://scikit-learn.org/0.13/modules/cross_validation.html, there's a separate function for generating stratified folds.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, you are right, I have re-edited my code, and ran it  for around 50 times. While the results have improved slightly, the auc values are still far from 0.79, it is 0.62. Thank you

Comment: Which parameters of the Random Forests did you adjust? You should check that the number of estimators, the number of sampled features per split and the maximum depth is the same (at least).

Comment: @AndreasMueller, the number of estimators were set to 10 for both, the maximum depth and sample features were also set to 10, and auto. Still different results :) :) :)

Comment: That's not good :( can you open an issue on the scikit-learn issue tracker please? Maybe the others know something I overlooked. Does features='auto' do the same thing for both implementations?

Comment: Thanks @AndreasMueller, thats a really good idea, I have posted the issue in scikit-learn issue tracker :). As for the features='auto', I am not sure what it means, so I set it to 10, which i did the same for the "features" in weka

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After posting the question at scikit-learn issue tracker, I got feedback that the problem is in the "predict" function I used. It should have been "pred_test = clr.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]" instead of "pred_test = clr.predict(X_test)", since the classification problem is binary: either 0 or 1.

After implementing the change, the results turned out to be the same for WEKA's and scikit's random forest :)